# Create a Woocommerce My Account Orders page showing only Completed orders

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, orders

I deleted a previous question as it was poorly worded on my part. I'm trying to create a Woocommerce My Account Orders page that only shows completed orders. I have tried the following code but all of the orders still show regardless of status.

```
function woocommerce_orders() {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ($user_id == 0) {
        return 
do_shortcode('[woocommerce_my_account]');
    } else {
        $orders = wc_get_orders(array(
            'customer' => $user_id,
            'status'   => 'completed', // You can 
modify the order status as needed
        ));
        $order_count = count($orders);
        ob_start();
        wc_get_template('myaccount/my-orders.php', 
array(
            'current_user' => get_user_by('id', 
$user_id),
            'order_count' => $order_count
        ));
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
add_shortcode('woocommerce_orders', 'woocommerce_orders');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since WooCommerce 3 the template `myaccount/my-orders.php` is deprecated, no longer used and replaced by myaccount/orders.php.

The difference between those templates is that the old one use a WP_Query hard-coded in the template itself and the newest one uses a WC_Query *(compatible with [WooCommerce HPOS](https://woo.com/document/high-performance-order-storage/))*.

As you use `myaccount/my-orders.php` template *(the deprecated one)* in your shortcode, you need something different, to target customer completed orders:

```php
add_shortcode('woocommerce_orders', 'shortcode_my_account_orders');
function shortcode_my_account_orders() {
    global $current_user;

    if ($current_user->ID > 0) {
        ob_start(); // Start buffering

        add_filter('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 'custom_my_account_my_orders_query', 10);

        wc_get_template('myaccount/my-orders.php', array(
            'current_user' => $current_user,
        ) );

        remove_filter('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 'custom_my_account_my_orders_query', 10);

        return ob_get_clean();
    } else {
        return do_shortcode('[woocommerce_my_account]');
    }
}

// Filter WP_Query for deprecated my-orders.php template
function custom_my_account_my_orders_query( $query_args ) {
    // Only completed orders
    $query_args['post_status'] =['wc-completed'];
    
    return $query_args;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! For some reason the list has a title above it labeled "Recent Orders", is there a way to change that? Last thing, is there a way to show a SVG image if the shortcode retruns no value (no "completed" orders)? If not, I'd be Ok with text saying "You have no completed orders". Thanks!